# SHAP Linear model waterfall with KernelExplainer and LinearExplainer

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, classification, shap

I am working on binary classification and trying to explain my model using SHAP framework.

I am using logistic regression algorithm. I would like to explain this model using both `KernelExplainer` and `LinearExplainer`.

So, I tried the below code from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599628/how-to-export-shap-local-explanations-to-dataframe)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from shap import TreeExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

idx = 9
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
background = shap.maskers.Independent(X, max_samples=100)
explainer = KernelExplainer(model,background)
sv = explainer(X.iloc[[5]])   # pass the row of interest as df
exp = Explanation(
    sv.values[:, :, 1],         # class to explain
    sv.base_values[:, 1],
    data=X.iloc[[idx]].values,  # pass the row of interest as df
    feature_names=X.columns,
)
waterfall(exp[0])
```

This threw an error as shown below

> AssertionError: Unknown type passed as data object: <class
> 'shap.maskers._tabular.Independent'>

How can I explain `logistic regression` model using `SHAP KernelExplainer` and SHAP LinearExplainer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculation-wise the following will do:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

from shap import LinearExplainer, KernelExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall
from shap.maskers import Independent

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

idx = 9
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)

explainer = KernelExplainer(model.predict, X)
sv = explainer.shap_values(X.loc[[5]])   # pass the row of interest as df

exp = Explanation(sv,explainer.expected_value, data=X.loc[[idx]].values, feature_names=X.columns)
waterfall(exp[0])
```

[image]

Note: `KernelExplainer` doesn't support maskers, and in this case either `loc` or `iloc` will return the same.

```
background = Independent(X, max_samples=100)
explainer = LinearExplainer(model,background)
sv = explainer(X.loc[[5]])   # pass the row of interest by index
waterfall(sv[0])
```

[image]

Note here, `LinearExplainer`'s result can be provided to waterfall "as-is"

Comment: under kernal explainer, what does `X.loc[[5]]` in used for? Is it used as a background point? And I see that you also use `X.loc[[idx]].values` as data. What is the difference between two?

Comment: btw, for linear explainer, why is the x-axis SHAP plot different. Since, we are focussing on binary classification, shouldn't it be as usual 0 to 1 (probability). Is it possible to change the scale of linear explainer output (to explain logistic regression which is binary classification)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error again wrt to waterfall plot for breast cancer data - `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'items'` when I execute the line `Explanation(sv,explainer.expected_value, data=X.loc[[idx]].values, feature_names=X.columns)`. I guess the issue could be with my system or packages etc.

Comment: If kernel explainer doesn't have background, masker, then it will run for long time. Isn't it? If I have to find shap values for all my records in the datatframe etc?

Comment: For KernelExplainer, background dataset is `X` total (you may see a warning message if it's larger than 100). The explanations are only calculated for `X.loc[[idx]]`, i.e. the datapoint of interest by index. For LinearExplainer, the background is calculated by masker. The difference is due to this fact I believe.

Comment: Okay, yeah but if we want to find shap value explanations for all our data points in dataframe, it may run for long time. Isn't it?, my point of interest is all points/rows in dataframe

Comment: For all point -- yes. I simply following your long standing logic: find SV for a datapoint by index.

Comment: Appreciate all your support and for your posts on SHAP in SO. I am learning and it is all useful for my graduate project. So, linear explainer cannot give us output in the scale of 0 to 1?

Comment: KernelExplainer: explaines function `model.predict` (i.e. proba for LogisticRegression). `LinearExplainer`: seem to predict and explain raw. Gimme some time, I'll look how to reconcile the two over weekend.

Comment: I benefit through your answers on SHAP in this forum. However, am reaching out to check wit you on a quick question. Do you know whether SHAP can be used for less frequently used regressors like Huber Regressor, LassoCV regressor etc. Are SHAP the only way to interpret them? I can create a new post and share my example if you have an idea of how this can be done?

Comment: I am not sure if there exist readily available fast SHAP solutions, but with KernelExplainer you can explain any function, including any ML model. Though KernelExplainer may take some time.